# When no records exists, should return non-zero for unread messages count

Tags: mysql

This is my table structure:

```
tblTickets
ticket_id | subject | creator_id | created_date | last_updated | category_id | ticket_status

tblMessages
msg_id | msg | ticket_id | replied_by | reply_time

tblReadBy   - PrimaryKey: (ticket_id,user_id)
ticket_id | user_id | last_read_time
```

Am trying to list all the tickets to the currently logged in User. That is, tickets that were created by them only.

Also, am showing a small color indication to let the the User know whether there's any unread messages.

So, whenever a User views a Ticket(by clicking from the list), a record will be either inserted/updated in `tblReadBy` with the `ticket_id` and `user_id` along with the current time)

My query for listing Tickets looks somewhat like this:

```
SELECT 
    t.`ticket_id`, 
    t.`subject`, 
    t.`user_id`, 
    t.`created_date`, 
    t.`last_updated`
    ( 
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM `tblReadBy` 
        WHERE `ticket_id` = t.`ticket_id` AND 
              `user_id` = 'XXX' AND 
              `last_read_time` < t.`last_updated` 
    ) AS `has_unread_msg`
FROM `tblTickets` AS t
WHERE t.`creator_id` = 'XXX'
ORDER BY t.`last_updated` DESC
```

Here, `XXX` is the user_id of the currently logged in User. This query works fine if there's a row in `tblReadBy` table for the currently logged in `user_id` and the `ticket_id`.

But if there's no row exists for this `user_id` and `ticket_id`, then as per logic it's an "unread ticket", but the query would return `0` for `has_unread_msg` column.

How can I fix this particular case?

**NOTE:** There would be more than one user replying to a Ticket. Like the actual User, Moderator (more than one), Admin, etc.

Thank you

---

**SOLUTION:**

So far, what I figured out is this:

```
SELECT 
    t.`ticket_id`, 
    t.`subject`, 
    t.`user_id`, 
    t.`created_date`, 
    t.`last_updated`
    ( 
        SELECT 
               COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN `last_read_time` < t.`last_updated` THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 1)
        FROM `tblReadBy` 
        WHERE `ticket_id` = t.`ticket_id` AND 
              `user_id` = 'XXX'                  
    ) AS `has_unread_msg`
FROM `tblTickets` AS t
WHERE t.`creator_id` = 'XXX'
ORDER BY t.`last_updated` DESC
```

Am still trying to test all possible cases.

Comment: Your unread_msg_count does not make sense. Instead it should be times_ticket_is_read

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, like I said earlier, `unread_msg_count` will work as expected if there's any records for the currently logged in `user_id` and the `ticket_id`. But if there's no records, then the logic will fail! There will be more than one person replying to the ticket. Like a User, Admin and Moderator.

Comment: As I understand from your table definition and current query, unread_msg_count is basically counting the number of times the use XXX has read this ticket before the ticket has been updated. `tblReadBy` has only one row for a combination of `user_id` and `ticket_id` ??

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, you can read that column name as `has_unread_msg` instead of `unread_msg_count`.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, I already mentioned that a row in `tblReadBy` will be either inserted/updated when a User view Ticket (there's separate `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE UPDATE...` query behind the scenes, which I didn't posted as it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`SUM()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function's `NULL` handling behavior. It will return `NULL` if no row exists.

> If the return set has no rows, SUM() returns NULL

MySQL automatically typecasts results of a Boolean comparison operator to 0/1. Using this behavior, we can can use `Sum()` and [`Coalesce()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce).

```
SELECT 
    t.`ticket_id`, 
    t.`subject`, 
    t.`user_id`, 
    t.`created_date`, 
    t.`last_updated`
    ( 
      -- coalesce handles case when no rows
      SELECT COALESCE(SUM(`ticket_id` > 0), 1)
      FROM `tblReadBy` 
      WHERE `ticket_id` = t.`ticket_id` AND 
            `user_id` = 'XXX' AND 
            `last_read_time` < t.`last_updated` 
    ) AS `has_unread_msg`
FROM `tblTickets` AS t
WHERE t.`creator_id` = 'XXX'
ORDER BY t.`last_updated` DESC
```

Comment: @VppMan check the updated answer; use the part below the horizontal line

Comment: Bhauya, this is what seems to be working: `SELECT COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN last_read_time < t.last_updated THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 1) FROM tblReadBy  WHERE ticket_id = t.ticket_id AND  user_id = 'XXX'`

Comment: @VppMan replace `COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN last_read_time < t.last_updated THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 1)` with `COALESCE(SUM(ticket_id IS NOT NULL), 1)`

Comment: I don't think what you suggested will work. Because in the WHERE condition `last_read_time < t.last_updated` is used. Which will fetch only those rows that matches that condition! So using `SUM()` on those rows again breaks the logic!

Comment: @VppMan have you tried my code ? Can you create a fiddle to prove the same. Based on my understanding, my solution should work.

Comment: @ Madhur Bhaiya, doesn't WHERE condition evaluates first? So all records that matches the WHERE condition. In my example, if a User has not viewed the Ticket, then there will be no records in `tblReadBy`. And if the User has viewed it earlier or atleast once, there will be one record and whenever User accesses the Ticket, the `last_read_time` will be updated for that record. In your solution you are still using `last_read_time < t.last_updated`... (contd..)...

Comment: ...(contd)... So, your query will return `1` in two cases. If there's no rows that matches the condition in `tblReadBy`, which is CORRECT. But the second case, if there's a record in db for `user_id = XXX` and `ticket_id = 1`, but the `last_read_time` is later than the `last_updated` then, because of the `last_read_time < t.last_updated` in WHERE condition, it will again return `1`, which is WRONG.

Answer (score 0):

This could work because it left joins the two tables to find out whether there are any records in tblReadBy and then uses the result in the subquery. Unfortunately I couldn't test it.

```
SELECT 
t.`ticket_id`, 
t.`subject`, 
t.`user_id`, 
t.`created_date`, 
t.`last_updated`
( 
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN r.`ticket_id` IS NULL THEN 1 
             ELSE COUNT(*) 
        END AS message_count
    FROM `tblReadBy` 
    WHERE `ticket_id` = t.`ticket_id` AND 
          `user_id` = 'XXX' AND 
          `last_read_time` < t.`last_updated` 
) AS `unread_msg_count`
FROM `tblTickets` AS t
LEFT JOIN `tblReadBy` AS r ON t.`ticket_id` = r.`ticket_id` AND
           r.`user_id` = 'XXX'
ORDER BY t.`last_updated` DESC
```

You might need to add r.`ticket_id` in the SELECT list of the outer query like so:

```
SELECT 
t.`ticket_id`, 
r.`ticket_id`,
t.`subject`, 
t.`user_id`, 
t.`created_date`, 
t.`last_updated`
( 
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN r.`ticket_id` IS NULL THEN 1 
             ELSE COUNT(*) 
        END AS message_count
    FROM `tblReadBy` 
    WHERE `ticket_id` = t.`ticket_id` AND 
          `user_id` = 'XXX' AND 
          `last_read_time` < t.`last_updated` 
) AS `unread_msg_count`
FROM `tblTickets` AS t
LEFT JOIN `tblReadBy` AS r ON t.`ticket_id` = r.`ticket_id` AND
           r.`user_id` = 'XXX'
ORDER BY t.`last_updated` DESC
```

Comment: thank you. It worked! But it will give duplicate records if there's more than one rows for the same Ticket in `tblReadBy` (because there will be more than one person replying to the same Ticket). So I added a `GROUP BY t.ticket_id` in the outer query. Its okay right?

Comment: ok, got it. I modified the LEFT JOIN to only select tickets from the respective user (if any) or to return NULL if there aren't any.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it you need to count both messages that has been update in tblReadBy and messages that are new and have never been read, that is they exists in tblTickets but not in tblReadBy.

Here is my solution that is a bit complicated, I would love to see someone improve it, but basically I join agains two `SELECT ... COUNT(*)´, one for completely new messages and one for updated

```
SELECT t.ticket_id, subject, t.user_id, created_date, last_updated, IFNULL(c1.count, 0) + IFNULL(c2.count, 0)
FROM tblTickets t
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ticket_id, user_id, COUNT(*) count
           FROM tblTickets t
           WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                             FROM tblReadBy r   
                             WHERE t.ticket_id = r.ticket_id 
                             AND t.user_id = r.user_id)
           GROUP BY ticket_id, user_id) AS c1 ON c1.ticket_id = t.ticket_id AND c1.user_id = t.user_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT r.ticket_id, r.user_id, COUNT(*) count
           FROM tblReadBy r
           JOIN tblTickets t ON t.ticket_id = r.ticket_id AND t.user_id = r.user_id
           WHERE r.last_read_time < t.last_updated
           GROUP BY r.ticket_id, r.user_id) AS c2 ON c2.ticket_id = t.ticket_id AND c2.user_id = t.user_id
WHERE t.user_id = 'aaa'
```

Comment: Thank you. It looks a bit complex. Am trying to understand the idea from your query first.